# How to use a color defined in CSS in a Sass file?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I'm currently working on a project where I'm creating a color picker in the WordPress theme customizer. I'm using the following code in my functions.php file to define a color picker and set the color as a CSS variable:

```
// Function theme support Stylesheets
function custom_wp_customize_style(){ ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        :root{
            --primary: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'color_primary', '#c6538c' ); ?>;
        }
    </style>

<?php }

// Hook theme support Stylesheets
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_wp_customize_style' );
```

I then want to use this color variable in my Sass file, like this:

```
$color: var(--primary);

section{
    background-color: darken($color, 10%);
}
```

However, when I try to compile my Sass file, I get the following error: `SassError: $color: var(--primary); is not a color.`

Is there a way to use a color defined in CSS in my Sass file? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just a guess, but the error says `$color` but in your Sass file your variable name is `$primary`  could there be a misusage in your variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just made a mistake while creating this topic. I will fix it.

Comment: Your scss doesn't know anything about your browser, so thats why you have copmpiler error. `darken` during sass compilation has unnown parameter.